# Derivative chain with matrix exponential

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, linear-algebra

I have defined the following functions:

```
g[A_] := Sqrt[Inverse[DiagonalMatrix[Total[A, 1]]]] . A . 
          Sqrt[Inverse[DiagonalMatrix[Total[A, 1]]]]
f[A_] := Total[MatrixExp[A], 2]
h[A_] := f[g[A]]
```

When I take the derivative to a certain element, I get the expected result:

```
D[h[{{a, b}, {c, d}}], {{a}}]  /. {a -> 1, b -> 0.2, c -> 0.2, d -> 0}
(* {-0.35459} *)
```

Because of computational efficiency in another programming language, I want to keep the derivatives of `f` and `g` separate, i.e.:

```
df = D[f[{{a, b}, {c, d}}], {a}];
dg = D[g[{{a, b}, {c, d}}], {a}];
```

How can I define `dh` in terms of `df` and `dg` to receive the exact same results as using `D[h]`?